# positioning new element based on position of existing element?

Tags: javascript, positioning, appendchild, getboundingclientrect

I am using the following code (Javascript within a webpage) to create a 'new' element in the DOM dynamically.  I wish to position this say 200px 'below' an existing element.  However my output has the positioning of the new element(s) all wrong...as if the position (top, left) I am specifying is ignored.

```
var _reference = document.getElementById("outputs");

for (_count = 0; _count < _limits; _count++) {

 var _structure = document.createElement("div"); 
 _structure.setAttribute("class", "container-fluid");
 _structure.setAttribute("id", "struct_" + _tally);
  if (_count === 0){
  _rect = _reference.getBoundingClientRect();  
    //get the bounding box of the "outputs" id element...
  document.getElementById("outputs").appendChild(_structure);   
  _structure.style.top = _rect.top + "200px";  //NOT positioned 200px below 'outputs'
  _structure.style.left = _rect.left;  //NOT positioned same position as 'outputs'
  }  //_count is "0"

}  //for loop
```

I would have thought this should be fairly straightforward...however it is driving me crazy...any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set _structure.style.position to 'relative', 'absolute', 'fixed', or 'sticky' in order to use top, left, right, bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess that answers my comment question in the previous post above.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your position to realtive or absolute in order for this to work, also note that position: absolute sets the position according to the nearest relative positioned parent while position: relative positions according to the current position of the element

Comment: Thank you ...I will give that a try later this evening.  Seems to make sense.  I suppose the syntax would be "_structure.style.position = absolute;" (or relative)...correct?  Thank you again, much appreciated.

Comment: Correct, only you might need to set absolute in quotation marks

Comment: Thank yo again for your help  :)